# Creating Nested Relationships for a Rails JSON API with ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to build a Rails API with the following JSON structure:

```
{ team: "team_name",
  players: players: [
    {
      name: "player_one",
      contracts: [
        {
          start_date: '7/1/2017',
          seasons: [
            {
              year: 2017,
              salary: 1000000
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "player_two"
    }
  ]
}
```

My models are set up as follows:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :contracts
end

class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  has_many :seasons
end

class Season < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
end
```

I'm currently using the following code, but I'd like to clean this up using ActiveModel Serializers (Or other clean solutions)

```
def show
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  render json: @team.as_json(
    except: [:id, :created_at, :updated_at],
    include: {
      players: {
        except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :team_id],
        include: {
          contracts: {
            except: [:id, :created_at, :updated_at, :player_id],
            include: {
              seasons: {
              except: [:id, :contract_id, :created_at, :updated_at]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

Additionally, the array items are showing in descending order by ID, I'm hoping to reverse that. I'm also hoping to order the players by the first contract, first season, salary.

Answer (score 1):

**Active Model Serializers** is a nice gem to fit into your needs. Assuming you would use [`0-10-stable`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable) branch (latest: 0.10.7), you can go in this way:

#### Serializers ([Doc](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md))

```
# app/serializers/team_serializer.rb or app/serializers/api/v1/team_serializer.rb (if your controllers are in app/controllers/api/v1/ subdirectory)
class TeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name # list all desired attributes here
  has_many :players
end

# app/serializers/player_serializer.rb
class PlayerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name # list all desired attributes here
  has_many :contracts
end

# app/serializers/contract_serializer.rb
class ContractSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :start_date # list all desired attributes here
  has_many :seasons
end

# app/serializers/season_serializer.rb
class SeasonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :year, :salary # list all desired attributes here
end
```

#### TeamController

```
def show
  @team = Team
    .preload(players: [contracts: :seasons])
    .find(params[:id])

  render json: @team, 
    include: ['players.contracts.seasons'], 
    adapter: :attributes
end
```

Note 1: Using `preload` (or `includes`) will help you [eager-load multiple associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations), hence saving you from **N + 1 problem**.

Note 2: You may wish to read the details of the `include` option in `render` method from [Doc](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option)

Answer (score -1):

I think your approach is right. Looks clean as it could be.
You can use also `named_scopes` on your Model.

See [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html) here.